# Generated standalone *.exe from python is not runnable

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

Though the conversion from *.py- to a standalone *.exe-file via the command "pyinstaller --onefile filename.py" can be completed successfully, the executable itself failes to run

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py",
>   line 13, in    File
>   "c:\users\user01\pycharmprojects\api4trd\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
>   line 623, in exec_module
>       exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)   File "lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 86, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources.py2_warn' [13560]
>   Failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres

following packages are used

1) math

2) datetime

3) yfinance

Python version: 3.8.1

pyinstaller version: 3.6

OS:W10

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one hidden import in your pyinstaller command. Although earlier version of Python and Pyinstaller never used to give this error, but nevertheless here is the solution

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=pkg_resources.py2_warn filename.py
```